# How do I limit the time a 3rd party process has to complete?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a 3rd party library (dll) that I don't have the source code for. I want to limit the elapsed time this dll has to complete its task. If it times out, I'm happy for it to move on to its next task.

I have tried using std::threads, but there is no terminate thread functionality. I want to try and keep boost out of my application, but I do know it supports terminate.

I could wrap the dll in its own exe and make a system call that I can kill after the specified time. But that seems inelegant.

What is the best way to call this dll's api, but kill it if it doesn't complete after a specified period of time?

Answer (score 1):

> I could wrap the dll in its own exe and make a system call that I can kill after the specified time. But that seems inelegant.

As archaic as it may feel, this is almost certainly the best approach.  You don't have the source code, and it's unlikely the documentation for the library routines you're calling say whether they acquire or lock any resources (e.g. heap memory, mutexes / critical sections, file handles, sockets).  If you force the thread to stop, those kind of resources may not be released/unlocked, and it could be that further functions in your program (even to C/C++ library code that both you and the terminated thread use such as heap allocation functions) may hang, crash or mis-function.

The only time I'd consider thread cancellation is when I know the thread is doing some work such as number crunching, and I've carefully crafted or inspected the code to ensure there's no further resource acquisition or locking....

It may even be better to let the thread continue running to termination in the background - ignoring the eventual results - if the machine isn't otherwise hungry for the CPU being wasted.

> I want to try and keep boost out of my application, but I do know it supports terminate.

I don't think that's true anyway.  boost supports a cooperative form of thread "interruption", but the code being run in the thread has to check at reasonable intervals whether it should continue running.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html

Answer (score 0):

The following MSDN link explains how to terminate treads. Note that this is a pretty drastic thing to do... and quite why you really want to do this is not clear (to me).

[Terminating a Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I use ifdefs for std::threads to terminate them with platform-specific code. I commonly use windows and linux, so

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <Windows.h>
    #define killThread(x) TerminateThread(x) // Need to pass std::thread::native_handle()
#else
    #include <pthread.h>
    #define killThread(x) pthread_close(x)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

First: you do *not* want to kill a thread, except as a last resort in case of a true emergency (like, the thread has gone wild and you need to kill it to protect the user's data). When/if you have to kill a thread, you almost always want to kill (and if necessary, restart) the process as soon afterwards as possible--the system can't really clean up after a thread is killed, so it can leave your process in a fairly (or thoroughly) unstable state.

As such, if you want to limit the time used by the DLL, you almost certainly want to wrap it into an executable, so when its time is up, you can kill the entire process, then continue from there.

Rather than just spawn it as a process so you need to directly monitor its CPU usage, it's probably easier to put it into a [job object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx). You can then specify a limit on the CPU usage for that process, and Windows will handle the monitoring for you. This also gives a (little) more flexibility in how you handle things when the process does use up all its CPU time (as well as being able to set other limits, such as maximum memory it uses, limit CPU usage at any given time (e.g., maximum of 15% CPU usage), and so on.